# how to solve this Complex Equation?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a doubt about the resolution of this equation:

$z^2 +|z^2 -1|=\frac{1}{2}(z+\bar{z})$

I tried to replace $z$ by $x+iy$ and $\bar{z}$ by $x-iy$.

From theory, I know that $|z|^2=z \cdot \bar{z}$, but I do not think this is the case ..

My question is: how do I evaluate $|z^2 -1|$ ?

After that, can I continue with the substitutions to solve the equation?

Thanks in advance: D

Comment: Can you apply the right things you said in lines 3 and 4 of your question to the complex number $z^2-1$? This way you could rewrite your equation in $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

$\left| z^2-1\right|\equiv \left| (x+yi)^2-1 \right|\equiv\left| x^2+2xyi-y^2-1\right|\equiv \left|[\color{green}{x^2-y^2-1}]+[\color{red}{2xy}]i\right|\equiv\sqrt{(\color{green}{x^2-y^2-1})^2+(\color{red}{2xy})^2}\equiv\sqrt{x^4+2x^2y^2-2x^2+y^4+2y^2+1}\equiv\sqrt{(x^2-2x+y^2+1)(x^2+2x+y^2+1)}$.

Comment: Reading my notes of analysis I found a wild thing but I can not continue .. can you help me do it?

Comment: Yeah- what don't you understand?

Comment: Thanks :D 

I arrived here : 

$(x+iy)^2 + \sqrt{(x^2 -y^2 -1)^2+(2xy)^2}=x$

After? :/

Comment: @SamueleMIllesoli Check that again- it's not right. Remember: to calculate $\left| z\right|,$ you use: $\left|z \right| \equiv \sqrt{\rm (real \ part)^2+ (imaginary \ part)^2}$

Comment: I'm so confused, also because of the language ... 
Could you play entirely? I have examined in the coming days and are in the most absolute panic ... I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\Im(z^2) = 2xyi = 0$, whence either $x=0$ or $y=0$. This makes calculating $|z^2-1|$ easy. You get: $(x^2-y^2)+|x^2-y^2-1| = x$.

If $x^2-y^2-1\leq0$, then $x=1$. Then $y=0$.
If $x^2-y^2-1>0$, then $2(x^2-y^2) - 1 = x$. Now, only $y=0$ is possible. And this leads to $2x^2-x-1 = (x-1)(2x+1) = 0$, leaving two possible solutions. However, neither solution satisfies the strict inequality.

The unique solution is therefore $x=1$ and $y=0$.

Comment: So..the solutions are :

$z=1+0i$ and $z=-1+0i$ ???

Comment: @SamueleMIllesoli, the astute observer would note that the $-1$ appears inside the absolute value. This has been corrected.

Comment: @SamueleMIllesoli, the unqiue solution is $z=1+0i$.